Hopping up and down with excitement
Is there a word for hopping up and down with excitement, in the way a child does in anticipation of a gift for example?

Closely related.

There are lots of phrases for excited kids, like bouncing off the walls (although I'd associate that and some others more with kids being restive, full of sugary drinks, and hyped-up or over-tired, than excited about a gift.) Being hyper is probably frowned upon these days as offensive to kids with ADHD and related disorders, and again is more for unprovoked, uncontrolled craziness. I doubt you'll find a single word with precisely that meaning.

@StuartF I don't think anyone with ADHD considers that usage of hyper offensive; I certainly don't.

Can you show how you would use this word in a sentence, inserting a _____ where the word would go?

"'We should go see them!' said he with _____." The word would convey the type of emotion I described in the question. I think probably glee or a synonym. I wondered if there was one word that specifically refers to the way a child feels in such a moment.

Oh, now we look for a noun. Putting that snowball aside, jumping for joy.

How about bubble over with excitement?

To exhibit or express some emotion that one is unable to contain.

The kids always bubble over with excitement on the last day of school before summer.
[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms]
bubble over with (something)

Certainly bubble over with excitement has a currency that may not be found in verbs like gambol, caper, cavort, prankle, scamper, skipper, curvet, tripudiate, firk, flisk, frolic, prance, dance, sally, fling, sault, bale, terp, subsult, pract, stend, exult, saltate, ebulliate.

Thank you. If I can't find a word for this, a good compromise would be then using a synonym of the emotion: like giddy, thrilled, etc..

I think, a word specifically for this not existing, either a verb or an adjective could be used: I need to tell someone to act that way. Frolic is very interesting since it is both a verb and an adjective--also a noun, but I don't think it applies here. Given this, it seems frolicsome may be the best compromise.


exuberate [verb; intransitive]:
1: to become exuberant; show exuberance

[He] exuberated over his victory


[Merriam-Webster]
and the adjective:

exuberant very energetic, and showing the happiness of being alive:

He is an exuberant dancer.


[Cambridge Dictionary]
(though I'd use a phrase instead)

In adjective form, I suggest JUBILANT: "feeling or expressing great happiness and triumph." Does that come close enough for your particular context?
